# bash: default output on empty input from pipe

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I'm trying to pipe a few different commands together. some of the command may return empty output. in such case i'd like to have some default output, not the empty one. how can i achieve it in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `read` command with a timeout, to see if it returns something and return some default output in cases when empty. This relies on the exit code returned by the `read` command on failure to read from an input stream.

```
.. | { read -r -t1 val || echo 'something' ; }
```

For example, trying to search needle in a haystack

```
echo haystack | grep needle | { read -r -t1 val && echo "$val" || echo 'something' ;  }
```

The general boilerplate template for this use-case using an if condition would be something like below and more verbosely written:

```
if read -r -t1 val < <(echo haystack | grep needle); then 
    printf '%s\n' "$val"
else 
    printf '%s\n' "something"
fi
```

You could replace the part `echo haystack | grep needle` with the command you are tying to work with.

Comment: The biggest problem with this approach is that it assumes the command will produce its output within 1 second (or whatever threshold you choose). (Which is not to say there is a *better* approach, short of knowing more about the command involved, but it's something to be aware of.)